# Audio Classification

Tags: noise, spectrogram, audio-processing, noise-cancellation

Most of the paper about audio classification has worked like this they have specific sounds class wise and the did classification. What if the audio files i have collected have two different sounds at same time for example car engine and footsteps how to remove one sound or suppress one sound from other during classification how to treat this kinds of audio files.

Comment: ooooh... [Source Separation](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Audio_Source_Separation/ib9ODwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover).  Very tough nut to crack.